# The index was outside the allowed range. Why?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my C# code, and I can't make a solution for problem. So, my problem I get an exception when I try to login. There isn't any fixed element object. Where is the problem in the code? Exception:

> The index was outside the allowed range. Parameter: index

Code:

```
    public dbresult.GetSome Get(Oneword.dbcon conn, string tablename) {
        string constring = "Server=" + conn.Host + ";Database=" + conn.Database + ";Uid=" + conn.Username + ";Pwd=" + conn.Password;
        int i,im=0;

        Oneword.dbresult.GetSome result = new dbresult.GetSome();
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(constring);

        connection.Open();

        try {
            MySqlDataReader oszlopok_cmd = null;
            MySqlDataReader sorok_cmd = null;

            DataTable oszlopok = null;

            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM "+tablename;

            // Oszlopok lekérése
            oszlopok_cmd = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);
            oszlopok = oszlopok_cmd.GetSchemaTable();
            oszlopok_cmd.Close();

            List<string> columns = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow col in oszlopok.Rows) {
                columns.Add(col.Field<String>("ColumnName"));
            }

            // Sorok lekérése, és tárak feltöltése
            sorok_cmd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sorok_cmd.Read()) {
                i = result.AddNewDir();

                foreach (string clomone in columns) {
                    result.AddKeyValue(i, clomone, sorok_cmd.GetString(im));
                    im++;
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            connection.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }

public class dbresult {
    public class GetSome {
        private List<Dictionary<string, string>> dirlistem = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        private int cuID = 0;

        public void AddKeyValue(int dirID, string key, string value){
            dirlistem[dirID][key] = value;
        }
        public int AddNewDir() {
            Dictionary<string,string> added = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            cuID++;
            return cuID - 1;
        }
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetDir(int dirID) {
            return dirlistem[dirID];
        }
        public void ModifyValue(int dirID, string key, string value) {
            dirlistem[dirID][key] = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Specifying the line that throws the exception could be very helpful... but have you tried debugging and seeing what is happening on that line? Sounds like you are trying to get something that is not there.

Comment: I would think it is the arrayed object. You need to find what line the problem is on The exception will tell you. Then you can tell us what object is causing the error or debug it yourself to find out why it is going over.

Comment: connection.Close(); or when I insert the catch { throw; } in throw;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding created dictionaries to list:

```
public int AddNewDir() {
  Dictionary<string,string> added = new Dictionary<string,string>();
  // ***
  dirlistem.Add(added);
  // ***
  cuID++;
  return cuID - 1;
}
```

Hence, any place where you have `dirlistem[dirID]` will throw an exception.

Also, you do not need `cuID` member in `GetSome` class. Simply

```
return dirlistem.Count - 1;
```

from `AddNewDir`.